# Spring message converters

Tags: json, spring, message

I have overriden JsonConvertor in our application and configured the convertor in the below way

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
 <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
    <bean class="com.test.iv.converters.JsonConverter"  />
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But the issue i am getting is for one use case where our use case is returning string(which already got converted to json using gson) with @ResponseBody annotation on a method, again this JsonConvertor is getting called because the media type is application Json .. When i didn't override this StringHttpMessageConverter used to get called because StringHttpMessageConverter comes earlier than default jsonconvertor .. so i had to fix the issue by specifying like below

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="com.test.iv.converters.JsonConverter"  />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But i am just wondering, this kind of conflict might come with other convertors as well, So i want to specify all the convertors in xml. Can you please help me with all the convertors with the default order so that i can inject them into my xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So i want to specify all the convertors in xml.

You shouldn't have to do this. See the XSD in `spring-mvc` for the `register-defaults` parameter:

> Whether or not default HttpMessageConverter registrations should be added in addition to the ones provided within this element.

You've explicitly set this to `true`, which means that your converter is getting registered *in addition* to the default converters.

What you probably need to do is to set the `supports()` method of your custom converter to not accept plain `String` objects so that the conversion will fall through to the default `StringHttpMessageConverter`.

**Answering your question as-asked anyway:**

In spring 4.1, the default message converters are:

`ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`, `StringHttpMessageConverter`, `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`, `SourceHttpMessageConverter`, and `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter`. Then, if the appropriate libraries are available: `AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter` and `RssChannelHttpMessageConverter`, `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter`,  `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, and `GsonHttpMessageConverter`.

This happens in `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, specifically the `addDefaultHttpMessageConverters` method ([here on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L682)).